# How to remove "_log" from the column title of my CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file with the column titles: `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11`

I used Pandas to read the CSV file, but got the following error:

```
ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.
                Did not expect the data types in fields 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11_log
```

How did `_log` come in here? How can I remove it? I went to the original CSV file but couldn't spot such addition and was thus not able to remove it manually.

Thanks.

**EDIT-1**

You can kindly find the CSV file I'm talking about, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw79sgtff1dzev3/train.csv?dl=1).

**EDIT-2**

I'm using this statement to read the CSV file"

```
data_train = pd.read_csv(input_path + 'train.csv', sep=';')
```

**EDIT-3**

I changed to `sep=','` above, but now getting the following (weird, look at those `u'`s and `_log`s!):

```
ValueError: feature_names mismatch: [u'0', u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'6', u'7', u'8', u'9', u'10', u'11', u'0_log', u'1_log', u'2_log', u'3_log', u'4_log', u'5_log', u'6_log', u'7_log', u'8_log', u'9_log', u'10_log', u'11_log'] [u'-1.3798', u'2.4132', u'13.8796', u'4.4036', u'2.5675', u'1.3097', u'0.92286', u'-14554.0704', u'10099.9967', u'-15572.1921', u'23.3675', u'1.2285', u'-1.3798_log', u'2.4132_log', u'13.8796_log', u'4.4036_log', u'2.5675_log', u'1.3097_log', u'0.92286_log', u'-14554.0704_log', u'10099.9967_log', u'-15572.1921_log', u'23.3675_log', u'1.2285_log']
expected 1_log, 11_log, 3_log, 9_log, 5_log, 0_log, 10_log, 1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 2_log, 8_log, 6_log, 7_log, 11, 10, 4_log in input data
training data did not have the following fields: 1.3097_log, -1.3798_log, 13.8796_log, 1.2285_log, -15572.1921_log, 2.4132, 0.92286, 10099.9967_log, -15572.1921, -1.3798, 10099.9967, 0.92286_log, 2.5675_log, -14554.0704_log, 1.3097, 23.3675_log, 2.5675, 1.2285, 13.8796, 4.4036, 2.4132_log, -14554.0704, 4.4036_log, 23.3675
```

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 Thanks for your kind reply. No really, nothing at all.

Comment: Maybe you can post 2-3 first lines of our csv here?

Comment: When you open it using something like excel, are there any extra columns with values? It could be something where there is an extra value or space somewhere that is making it seem like there is an extra column and causing the _log to be picked up from another line?

Comment: show your code please. also are you using windows?

Comment: show code and part of CSV file.

Comment: I have added the CSV file and code statement I'm using to read the CSV file.

Comment: I can read it without any problem directly from internet - `pandas.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw79sgtff1dzev3/train.csv?dl=1')` Maybe you has mistake in code. Or you work with different file which has `_log` somewhere.

Comment: I cannot access dropbox, is it possible to copy paste the first 5 line of your csv ad the code you read it?

Comment: `sep` should be `','`  not `';'`

Comment: `_log` is not in the original file.  Please show us the code you use to read the file.

Comment: I can read the file you have shared with sep=','

Comment: is it comma separated or ; separated?

Comment: @Rebin it is comma separated but even with `sep=";"` I can read it without error - I only get all in one column.

Comment: @GiraffeMan91 I saved the file as "xlsx" and opened it in that format, but nothing showed up (i.e. _log).

Comment: @Rebin I'm using MAC OS X

Comment: since I dont have access to the train.csv file (dropbox is restricted in my situation) so I cannot see the file lol!!

Comment: check `print(input_path + 'train.csv')` and use this path to open in any editor - as for me you have two files - one with `_log` which you open in code, second without `_log` which you check in editor.

Comment: I know that when you go from win to ubuntu and would like to use files that are saved in win previously and open it in ubuntu, there are many times that win is adding many chars at the end. so, are you able to save it as simple txt? so probably ppl here is opening in win, and dont see what you see as a problem.

Comment: @Rebin I tried copying and pasting the first few lines from the CSV file, but when trying to paste in StackOverflow it gets pasted as an image, which I think wouldn't be helpful?

Comment: @Rebin The CSV file originally came from Ubuntu and moved to a MAC OS X

Comment: @furas I printed the path, and it is the same file I'm using which I expect should be without the extra characters.

Comment: looks like going from one OS to another OS cused the problem, maybe check for unicode symbol too.

Comment: Your csv seems to use utf-8 encoding. Try passing `encoding='utf-8'` to `read_csv`

Comment: show FULL error message - it looks like you have error in different part of code - when you use data in prediction, not when you read it. Or better show full code. It seems we try resolve problem which doesn't exist because you have problem in different part of code.

Answer (score 0):

I do that:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw79sgtff1dzev3/train.csv?dl=1')
```

[image]

or

```
url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw79sgtff1dzev3/train.csv?dl=1'
df = pd.read_csv(url, names=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],header=0)
```